# Are these two definitions of an NP-Complete problem equivalent?

Tags: algorithm, np, np-complete

Definition 1 (usual definition)
A problem B is NP-Complete if

- B is in NP
- For C in NP, C is polynomal-time reducible to B

Definition 2 (in a few documents)
A problem B is NP-Complete if

- B is in NP
- if B  admits a polynomial-time algorithm, then all problems in NP  also admit a polynomial-time algorithm

(as in "On the Inherent Intractability of Certain Coding Problems,..., Berlekamp, McEliece and Tilborg" and other documents

Answer (score 1):

Definition 1 is the definition of NP-completeness you get if you define reducibility to be *polynomial-time mapping reducibility* (sometimes called *polynomial-time many-one reducibility*). That is, you’re allowed to reduce one problem to another by doing polynomial work to transform the input, then make a single call to the target problem. This is the standard definition of NP-completeness.

Definition 2 is the (nonstandard) definition of NP-completeness you get if you use *polynomial-time Turing reducibility* (called [Cook reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Turing_reductions)), in which you are allowed to spend polynomial time including an arbitrary number of calls to an oracle (solver) for the problem you’re reducing to.

Comment: Many thanks to templatetypedef, things become much clearer now, but I see that I  have to learn much more !